# Explicitly state type-arguments in type pattern is the only way to pattern match although eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider the following code:

```
trait Trait {
  type X
  type Y[_ <: X]
} 

type T[X0,Y0[_ <: X0]] = Trait { type X = X0; type Y[S <: X0] = Y0[S] }

class TraitImpl extends Trait {
  override type X = Int
  override type Y[I <: Int] = List[I]
}

case class Wrap[X,Y[_ <: X]](t: T[X,Y])

val wrap = new Wrap[Int,List](new TraitImpl) // why explicitly write types?
```

Why explicitly write types, see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611072/class-a-has-one-type-parameter-but-type-b-has-one).
Now I want to pattern match on `wrap`:

```
wrap match {
  case w: Wrap[_,_]      => // error
  case w: Wrap[_,_[_]]   => // error
  case Wrap(t)           => // error
  case w: Wrap[Int,List] => // fine
}
```

I am used to have several choices for pattern matching, in particular the last two `case` statements, sometimes the first one.
But none of the first three `case`s are working, why? (especially `case Wrap(t) =>`)?